# I am getting TLE in CSES Dice Combinations Question

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am getting TLE error when I tried to submit my python code in CSES. It is the first problem of CSES Problem Set.

Below is my Python code

CODE:

```
import sys,io,os
input = io.BytesIO(os.read(0, \os.fstat(0).st_size)).readline
n=int(input())
mod=1000000007
if(n>=1 and n<7):
    print(2**(n-1))
else:
    dp=[0]*(n+1) 
    dp[0]=1 
    dp[1]=1
    for i in range(2,7):
        dp[i]=2*dp[i-1]
    for i in range(7,n+1):
        dp[i]=(dp[i-1]%mod+dp[i-2]%mod+dp[i-3]%mod+dp[i-4]%mod+dp[i-5]%mod+dp[i-6]%mod) %mod
    sys.stdout.write(str(dp[n]%mod)+"\n")
```

Please suggest me the necessary optimizations

Comment: What is the issue? How should it behave? Do you have a specific error? You have to do the job of explaining what is potentially wrong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some optimizations you can do. dp[i] is already after modulo, so need not do

```
dp[i]=(dp[i-1]%mod+dp[i-2]%mod+dp[i-3]%mod+dp[i-4]%mod+dp[i-5]%mod+dp[i-6]%mod) %mod
```

But Just:

```
dp[i] = (dp[i-1] + dp[i-2] + dp[i-3] + dp[i-4] + dp[i-5] + dp[i-6])%mod
```

you can also get rid of the whole dp array. If your observe dp[i] only depends on 6 previous elements, so you can just maintain an array of just size 6 and update that array post every iteration.

Your time complexity will still be O(n) but you will reduce the constant factors.

Furthermore, this recurence of f(n) = f(n-1) +  f(n-2) + .... f(n-6) can also be solved in Log(N) time using matrix exponentiation, which is a little more involved, let me know if you'd like to know how to solve this problem in Log(N) time.